# SSL compatibilty in java 1.4

Tags: java, ssl, sni

I have searched for a number of posts but cannot find the answer.

Is there any way possible i could use SNI in java 1.4.
I checked that the API is available in java7 but is there any workaround to use SNI in java 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSSE (Java Secure Socket Extension) is an API defined to implement SSL in java. All clases under `javax.net` and `javax.net.ssl` are part of this standard.

Server Name Indication (SNI) is an extension the should be implemented by the specific JSSE Implementation. The SunJSSE version included in Sun Java 1.4 doesn't support SNI, so you need to register another JSSE provider that suports SNI.

Here you have a list of different JSSE providers (implementators):

https://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/AlternativeJSSE

You will have to register one than supports SNI.